# Magento: Category Name vs Page Title Name

Tags: category, category-attribute, page-title

How can a page title name (not meta) be different from the Category "Name"?

For example:

**Main Category 1:** `ABC`

**Sub-Category (under ABC):** `DEF`

On the navigation menu, the main category is displayed as "ABC" and the sub-category as `DEF`. However, when I user clicks on the DEF sub-category, how can the page title (on the page) be something other than the (default) DEF name? For example, `DEF Stuff`.

In other words, how can we have a page title (on the page; not meta) that is different from the category Name (field)?

Comment: Which Magento version are you using? The page title can be different from the Name and therefore this should answer you question?

Comment: currently 1.9.2.0

Comment: Indeed there is a different field for Page Title but from what I see the data entered there appear on meta (browser Page Title) and not on the actual page (title).

Comment: When I'm back to a place with normal internet I can paste the code I've used to do that so Monday morning ;-)

Answer (score 2):

you can add a new category attribute called `page_title`.  [Here is a tutorial on how to do it](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/).
Then edit the template `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` and replace

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

with

```
<h1>
<?php if ($category->getPageTitle()):?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getPageTitle(), 'page_title') ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?>
<?php endif;?>
</h1>
```

now you can fill in for your `DEF` category the field page title with `DEF stuff` and it will be displayed on the page. If you don't fill in the page title field, the category name will be used.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marius! I'll follow you your instructions and get back to you!

Comment: @Marius, I have same issue. I tryed this solution but not work on my site magento 1.9.3.1... Do you have another suggest?

Comment: Suppose you want the page title also as the html ahref title attribute in the menu? (Navigation php block)